# OnCollisionEnter(collision) function called even without collision occurring in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a first-person shooter game in Unity, where spheres are fired and should be destroyed if it hits the surrounding cubes. Spheres are created by mouse click.

The function OnCollisionEnter(collision) is called before the sphere collides with anything. i.e, it is called straight away when a new sphere is created, even if there is no collision and it destroys the sphere straight away.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
        Debug.Log("OnCollisionEnter - MOVER");
        DestroyObject(gameObject);
}
```

The code is written in the Mover file for the sphere.

Any help would be much appreciated as I am new to unity.

Comment: you can check what object your spehere is colliding debugging the collision argument. All the info is there. check https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html. The sphere must be colliding with the gun that shoots it, or some gameobject near by wherever its instantiated

Answer (score 0):

You have some object in your scene with this script on it which has its collider in range of your gun. It may be the colliders on the cube are humungous or you accidentally attached this script on a gameobject you didnt intend to. If you type the full script name in the search bar above your gameobject hierarchy it will show every game object that has the script.

Answer (score 0):

`OnCollisionEnter` is called for any collision of current game object in the scene. if you want to call this function for a specific game object like `Player` or `Enemy` or etc. , assign a tag to your object and check it with you `collision` object's tag.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.tag == "Player")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```